# Entry URI Format from an Entries Field (Categories)

Tags: categories, entries-field

i am trying to set the url format for some entries to include the category slugs set for it within a category entry field - i can get the first one like this

```
{eventCategory.one().slug}/{slug}
```

but cannot figure out how to get the second one (the 2nd one is optional and is a sub-cat of category1 also so not sure how to do some optional logic for it within the 'Entry URI Format')

so the url could be
category1/slug OR
category1/catgeory2/slug

Any ideas anyone? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.all()` to get all selected categories in order. Since the URI format is a Twig template, you can use some Twig filters to output all selected categories as path segments:

```twig
{{ eventCategory.all()|column('slug')|join('/')/{{ slug }}
```

The `column` filter will extract the `slug` property from the array of entries, and `join` will join the array of slugs to a single string separated by slashes `/`.

This will result in `category1/slug` for an entry with only one category, and `category1/category2/slug` for entries with two categories. It will also work for any number of selected categories (though you may want a different format in this case).